# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I'm currently developing a blog application.I use react js for frontend and node js for backend.I have this isAuthenticated method.

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
    return false;
}

if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {

    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));

}
 else {
    return false;
}};
```

and I use it here

```
 <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link
                        to={`/user/${isAuthenticated().user._id}`}
                        style={isActive(history, `/user/${isAuthenticated().user._id}`)}
                        className="nav-link"
                    >
                        {`${isAuthenticated().user.name}'s profile`}
                    </Link>
                </li>
```

And it's giving me error of TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined in 
  to={`/user/${isAuthenticated().user._id}`} this part

Please help I'm stocked I can't get the _id from backend I think but I can jwt token whenever I click the application in google chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can not only return localStorage item but also can return false.

**So make proper checks like this**

```js
isAuthenticated() ? (
  <Link
    to={`/user/${isAuthenticated().user._id}`}
    style={isActive(history, `/user/${isAuthenticated().user._id}`)}
    className="nav-link"
  >
    {`${isAuthenticated().user.name}'s profile`}
  </Link>
) : (
  <Link
    to={`/login}`}
    className="nav-link"
  >
    Login
  </Link>
)
```

Comment: is there a way I can change my isAuthenticated because there are couple parts I use that method in too

Answer (score 1):

You try to get object with *user* property from *isAuthenticated* function but it returns only string or boolean.

Comment: JSON.parse does not return a string unless your JSON is just a string.
In this case it most likely returns an object, but typescript doesn't know about the structure of that object.

Comment: It is not a typescript. It is just TypeError because he tries to get property from primitive.

Comment: Ahh, sorry you're right. I'm too focused on TS right now.

Comment: What should I type instead of that

Comment: You could decode the JWT token if it contains the user object.
If it doesn't, you need to make a separate API call to get the user object. JWT is just a framework and doesn't automatically define your user information. By default it's only used as some kind of password replacement when talking to an API.